# Temporarily override DNS settings in Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

When I release a new version of my web application, I try it first on a staging website, which is basically a clone of the production environment.

It's not enough for me to access the staging server by typing the IP address in my browser, as the application uses virtual hosts and thus replies on several domains and sub-domains.

What I'd like to do ideally, is temporarily override my DNS settings in Chrome, to force it to load mydomain.com and *.mydomain.com from the clone server.

I can do it from my hosts file, but it's quite cumbersome, and I doubt the changes will be taken into consideration immediately (and without a restart of Chrome), both to set the temporary DNS and to revert them back to their default value.

**Is there a way in Chrome to temporarily send all requests for a given domain name to a given IP address?**

Comment: Have you tried giving your DNS server an extremely low ttl?

Comment: @MDMoore313 I've read some stuff about very low TTL not always being respected by some implementations, and I was looking for something instant!

Comment: In FireFox, the [Redirector add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/redirector/) does everything you asked for.

Answer (score 3):

I think you've got the answer right in your question,

> I can do it from my hosts file, but it's quite cumbersome, and I doubt
>   the changes will be taken into consideration immediately (and without
>   a restart of Chrome), both to set the temporary DNS and to revert them
>   back to their default value.

The Hosts File will redirect your requests immediately, and you will not need to restart chrome. (I just tested on my PC)

Also the Cumbersome nature can be mitigated by keeping the file open, and using # to comment/comment the IP's needed.

Give the Hosts file another go without closing it (Make sure you run your editor as admin to speed things along)

1. Make the needed changes
2. Save the file
3. Run your Tests
4. Comment out the changes
5. Save again

That should fit within your few seconds time window

Comment: Unfortunately the browser caches name <=> ip. So, after changing the hosts file, you need to restart the browser. I am looking for a plugin in the browser to switch ip <=> name instantly

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to disappoint, but DNS is not an instant standard. If I understand you correctly though, you want to load an entirely different site in chrome from a different server. This is doable.

If the production site is yourdomain.com and the development site is test.yourdomain.com, in your DNS server you want to create an alias for test that points to it's IP address, there's is no need (and you actually *shouldn't*) change the IP to yourdomain.com. Consider a snippet of the DNS settings for example.com (your production site):

```
NAME                    TYPE   VALUE
--------------------------------------------------
test.example.com.        A      192.0.2.23
```

I don't know you manages your DNS, or what they used as a DNS server, but the implementation is the same.

Comment: I understand. My question is rather *is it possible to temporarily FAKE the DNS for Chrome, just for a few seconds?*

Comment: Not that I know of, but I could be wrong. Why exactly would you need to do that?

Comment: To test a new application on my clone environment while using the same domain name. I guess the *same domain name* is my problem!

Comment: @Benjamin that's what I'd say, yes!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, chrome have a feature to let you manipulate your DNS, but that is limited to corporate account only:

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=54693

This actually can change where the page point to for your entire company.

Comment: I guess that's not exactly what I'm looking for, but thanks anyway for mentioning it!

Answer (score 0):

Method 2, do the dirty tricks on the your network card.

idea: get another network card on your machine, which is directly connect to the staging machine. (separate network) with same IP address, or NAT by router to same IP address.

Then you can do switching environment by pulling plugs.